# Repeating a method multiple times per thread loop

Tags: java, swing, timer

To give some background information, I'm currently working on a Java coded pinball game. I'm keeping it in an MVC design model. It has a fairly realistic physics system that allows it to work collisions, gravity, friction etc. The system runs on a 20 FPS system right now.

The problem I'm having is that the physics loop that checks for collisions in the system works by running a method that using the current velocity of the ball calculates the time until the next collision. The most effective way for this to work would obviously be to keep running the check to account for the movement of the ball between checks to get it as accurate as possible, and if the time until collision is less than the time until the next check, then carry out the collision.

However, right now the system I am working with can only run the loop 20 times per second, which does not provide as accurate results as I would like, particularly during times of high acceleration, such as at ball launch.

The timer loop that I use is in the controller section of the MVC, and places a call to the physics section, located within the model. I can pass in the time remaining at the time the method is called in the controller, which the physics system can use, however I don't know how to run the loop multiple times while still tracking the remaining time before the next screen refresh?

Ideally I would like to run this at least 10 times per screen refresh. If anybody needs any more information please just ask.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the actual problem is that you do not know when the the collision will happen and when the next frame update is?

Shouldnt these be seperate running tasks? One thread that manages the collision detection and one that does the updating? each thread can run on its own interval (Timer.addTask(...)) and they should propebly be synchronized so colission/location updates are not performed when the render thread is executed.

Hope this answers your question.

Regards, Rob.